# android studio 3.4.3: unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, build

My build file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.xkcd_finder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google/gson
    implementation group: 'com.google', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

}
```

As it stands, I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google:gson:2.8.5
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

I have tried restarting, but that didn't work -- the error persisted.

How do I fix this? (I wish I could go back in time and not update Android Studio...:()

Comment: maybe this: see both answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779109/2711811

Answer (score 2):

The error `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google:gson:2.8.5` means Gradle can't resolve the dependency, so the first thing I would do is check your repository for the correct information (e.g., https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5).

Doing that, I can see that your group name is wrong, it should be:

`implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'`.